# MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate ios5 didnot find

Tags: iphone, ios5

i have develop one app in ios4.0. in which i implementing the code of SMS and it works great but when i run in ios 5 it get me error like did not find MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol whereas i am already imported MessageUI/MessageUI.h , MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. just change the deployment target of your project to 4.0 and it works..

Answer (score 4):

Just add the Message Framework imports:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the MessageUI framework from your build settings and add it again